# Is there a way I can transfer removed apps from app store from iPhone to Mac as IPA file?

Tags: apple-configurator, ios

I have an app installed on my iPhone which has now been removed from the app store. Is there a way I can transfer it from my iPhone to a Mac as a .ipa file? I remember some sort of way to do this with Apple Configurator but I cannot find the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the file with configurator, only add it.
To get the file to the Mac in the first place, you need an old version of iTunes that still has the App Store in it to pull them from an existing iPhone/Pad. They used to be transferred to the Mac as part of a regular sync.
You can still get 12.6.3 direct from Apple via [this link](https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/itunes12/091-33628-20170922-EF8F0FE4-9FEF-11E7-B113-91CF9A97A551/iTunes12.6.3.dmg) - courtesy of [OSXDaily - Get iTunes 12.6.3 with App Store for Mac and Windows](https://osxdaily.com/2017/10/09/get-itunes-12-6-3-with-app-store/)

This is going to come with its own set of problems. I doubt it will run on anything newer than Mojave. It was designed for El Capitan iirc. You'll likely need to fire up a VM to do this if you're on a current macOS. I still have the structure in place from last time I did this a few years ago, but I don't currently have iTunes 12.6.3 to test. 12.6.3 is also incompatible with newer iTunes/Music Libraries, which is another good reason to want to air-gap this in a VM.

There may also be issues with it recognising newer phones - again, I can't test this.

Once you have the .ipa, then you can quite easily add it from Configurator 2. Connect the phone, right click its representation, Add > Apps… select the file & it will copy it straight across to the phone…

[image]

[image]

The file path to your .ipa files is inside your iTunes folder. Mine is customised to an external iTunes Library folder, so I'm not certain of the default - `/Volumes/OhDaSpace/iTunes_Remote/Mobile Applications/`